# Android Unchecking CheckBoxes on a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter. It countains CheckBoxes. When one of them is checked, I would like to have the others unchecked. I tried creating a `CheckBox` list, and then created a method to return this list, but it kept giving IndexOutOfBounds (I added the CheckBoxes to the list at the getView method).

[This is my adapter](http://pastebin.com/gzNzjSUJ).

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBoxListView"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_width="50px"/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/editTxtListView"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_width="680px"
    android:editable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not have a global integer representing the checked position and in the getview method see if the global variable's value and the position, for which getView is called, are same then make check box checked else unchecked.
Saw your code in the pastebin.
You are making it quite a complex thing.
Anyway, just a quick comment, 
Dont do *this.pos=position;*
in the getView().
Instead of this check *if(postion==this.pos){
//Check this checkbox}
else{
//uncheck this check box
}*
Also, "pos" should be controlled by the activity or the pojo itself handling the data for the list.

Comment: I think that if this works, I didn't understand how an adapter works. In which cases the getView method is called?

Comment: get view is called for all the rows of the list view which are currently visible on screen.
So if you have checked your box in the index=2, getView will be called from index=0 to list length and because only at 2nd position its checked, check sign will be drawn and for others only box will be drawn.
For better understanding of the adapters you can follow : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html and http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I tried, but this didn't work.. maybe I'm doing something wrong. I posted my code @ Pastebin because I couldn't figure how to do here.

http://pastebin.com/iAdJJ6tg